# Quick Javascript thought about document.getElementByClassName for fixing error

Tags: javascript

Quick JS question :

if you do something like :

```
var text = document.getElementByClassName("grid3").innerText;
```

what is the best way if you have multiple elements with that class?

Comment: It depends, what do you want, the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the best way if you have multiple elements with that class?

It depends which element you want to reference... your example will always fail because that method returns a `NodeList` regardless of the number of elements. Note that it's `getElementsByClassName` (plural "elements").

If you want to get the first:

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("grid3")[0].innerText;
```

If you want to get them all (in an array):

```
var allText = [].map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("grid3"), function (elem) {
    return elem.innerText;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its `document.getElementsByClassName("grid3")` with s...you will always get back an array of Objects. Therefore innerText will not work there.

You could get the innerText of single elements in this array like this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("grid3");
var text = el[0].innerText;
```

Or if you have just one element with that class, give it a id and use 
`var el = document.getElementById("yourelementsid");`

Here is a fiddle that shows how it works and not works:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w68Kd/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no method document.getElementByClassName, you lost "s".

document.getElementsByClassName always returns an array (or array-like object), so you have to loop througt this array to find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementByClassName() return a list of elements so you can use it as array.

```
var textArr = document.getElementByClassName("grid3");
for(var i = 0; i< textArr.length; i++){
   // here is your text
   var text = textArr[i].innerText;
 }
```